# How to unit test an observable with jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I've added some code to a constructor and now my unit tests are failing. The new code sets either true or false to `this.isFollowOnMode` from an observable:

```
import { CustomerGroupService } from 'customerGroup.service';

class HeaderBarController {
    private isFollowOnMode: boolean;

    constructor(private customerGroupService: CustomerGroupService) {
        'ngInject';

        //new code that is causing test to fail:

        this.customerGroupService.isFollowOnMode$ // will be true or false
            .subscribe((isFollowOnMode) => {
                this.isFollowOnMode = isFollowOnMode;
            });
    }

    // other stuff
}

export default HeaderBarController;
```

I get the following error in my unit test:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Controller: HeaderBarController should be defined FAILED
>   TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.customerGroupService.isFollowOnMode$'

And this is my unit test that is failing:

```
describe('Controller: HeaderBarController', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(module.name));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.service('customerGroupService', () => { });

    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $componentController) {
        this.$scope = $rootScope.$new();
        this.ctrl = $componentController('headerBar',
            {
                // locals
                $scope: this.$scope,
                $element: [{}],
                $attrs: [],
            },
            {
                // scope bindings
            }
        );
    }));

    it('should be defined', function () {
        expect(this.ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

So it seems I'm not setting `this.customerGroupService.isFollowOnMode$`. the default value for it should be false. in the unit test. I'm new to unit testing.

Comment: Just a remark, unless things have changed, `'ngInject'` in TypeScript/ESNext source code is known to be unreliable. It would be more robust to write `class HeaderBarController {static $inject = ['customerGroupService'];` alternately, you could use a decorator to automatically create the annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to observables but applies to service stubbing in general.

This

```
$provide.service('customerGroupService', () => {});
```

will result in a service without expected properties, also it's incorrect to use arrows instead of a constructor.

ngMock already offers a way to mock services:

```
let customerGroupServiceMock;

beforeEach(() => {
  customerGroupServiceMock = {
    isFollowOnMode$: Observable.of(true);
  };
  angular.mock.module({ customerGroupService: customerGroupServiceMock });
});
```

It's also possible to inject mocked services into controller directly instead of defining them in injector:

```
    this.ctrl = $componentController('headerBar',
        {
            // locals
            customerGroupService: customerGroupServiceMock,
            $scope: this.$scope,
            $element: [{}],
            $attrs: [],
        },
```

This is exactly what 'locals' mean.